# Selecting value from jquery combobox doesn't run search for fnFilter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fnfilter

I'm using https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox for dropdown select and when particular value get selected, it should run search fnFilter for datatable for jQuery. Value is selected fine and it puts value in input field but fnFilter doesn't run. Already tried with keydown mousedown change but any of the value doesn't work.

How can I execute fnFilter directly after selecting value from combobox?

```
    var selectSprint = $('.custom-combobox-input');
    selectSprint.keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var selectedSprint = $('.custom-combobox-input').val();
            sprintResults.fnFilter(selectedSprint);
        }
    });

    var selectSprint1 = $('.custom-combobox-input');
    selectSprint1.on('keydown mousedown change', function(event){
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var selectedSprint = $('.custom-combobox-input').val();
        sprintResults.fnFilter(selectedSprint);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. You have to identify exact li element id/class and write method for it:

```
    $('.ui-autocomplete').click(function(e) { 
        sprintResults.fnFilter($('.custom-combobox-input').val());
    });
```